# Does strong law of large numbers hold for an average of this triangular array containing "almost i.i.d." sequences?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If a sequence of $n$ i.i.d. positive random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ has the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=\mu<\infty$, then it is known that the strong law of large numbers (SLLN) holds: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\xrightarrow{a.s.}\mu$, even when the second moment is not finite.

I am wondering if it holds when the sequence contains one element with mean that increasing in $n$ (but not too fast).  In fact, I am asking a question about a triangular array.

In my particular case, I have a triangular array $\{\{X_{1n},\ldots,X_{(n-1)n}, X_{nn}$ where $X_{in}>0$ and independent across all rows and columns; $X_{1n},\ldots,X_{(n-1)n}$ are identical with $\mathbb{E}[X_{1n}]=1$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_{1n}^2]=e^{2(\log n)^{a}}$ where $0<a<1$; and $\mathbb{E}[X_{nn}]=e^{(\log n)^{a}}$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_{nn}^2]=e^{4(\log n)^{a}}$.  Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{(\log n)^{a}}}{n}=0$, the contribution of $X_{nn}$ to the average $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{in}$ is small, and, thus, maybe the SLLN holds "row-wise".  I can use the Chebyshev's inequality to prove the weak law of large numbers for this case.  However, my tool for proving almost sure convergence, the Borel-Cantelli lemma, seems to not work here at all (though I might not be using correctly).  Can someone help?

**Minor edits to above**: 
Per responses and comments, I corrected some typos as well as notation for the random variables, and clarified that what I am dealing is, in fact, a triangular array.

**Main edit**

I was asked in the comments/answers about where this question came from and more information about $X_i$'s.  Here I describe the setting from which this problem arose.

I am given a machine which takes $n$ as input.  As an output it gives me a sequence of $n$ random variables $X_{1n},\ldots,X_{nn}$, where:

$$X_{in}=\exp\left[\frac{f(n)\Gamma_{in}}{1+f(n)}-k\left(\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)}+\left[\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)}\right]^2\right)\right], \text{  when }i\neq S\\
X_{in}=\exp\left[f(n)\Gamma_i-k\left(\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)}+\left[\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)}\right]^2\right)\right], \text{  when }i=S\\$$
where $k=n^c$, $0<c<1$, the sequence $\Gamma_{1n},\ldots,\Gamma_{nn}$ contains $n$ i.i.d. chi-squared random variables, each with $k$ degrees of freedom (note, the number of degrees of freedom for each $\Gamma_{in}$ depends on $n$, however, the independence holds across rows), $f(n)=\sqrt{\frac{(\log n)^{a}}{k}}$, and $1\leq S \leq n$ is unknown.  I am interested in the average $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{in}$ and, specifically would like to show that, even though I don't know what $S$ is, $X_{Sn}$ does not impact the average for large enough input $n$.  The statement I want is this: for any $\epsilon>0$, with probability one there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{in}-1\right|<\epsilon$.

Using the formula for the moment generating function of chi-squared random variable, and the Taylor series expansion of $\log(1-x)$ around $x=0$, I arrive at the means:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}E[X_{in}]&=&\exp\left[\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(\log n)^{3a}}{k}}\right)\right]\approx1, \text{ when }i\neq S\\
E[X_{Sn}]&=&\exp\left[-\frac{k}{2}\log\left(1-2f(n)\right)-k\left(\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)}+\left[\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)}\right]^2\right)\right]\\
&=&\exp\left[kf^2(n)+\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(\log n)^{3a}}{k}}\right)\right]\\
&\approx&e^{(\log n)^a}
\end{array}$$
The second moments are computed similarly:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}E[X_{in}^2]&=&\exp\left[-\frac{k}{2}\log\left(1-\frac{4f(n)}{1+f(n)}\right)-2k\left(\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)}+\left[\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)}\right]^2\right)\right], \text{ when }i\neq S\\
&=&\exp\left[2kf^2(n)+\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(\log n)^{3a}}{k}}\right)\right]\\
&\approx&e^{2(\log n)^a}\\
E[X_{Sn}^2]&=&\exp\left[-\frac{k}{2}\log\left(1-4f(n)\right)-2k\left(\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)}+\left[\frac{f(n)}{1+f(n)}\right]^2\right)\right]\\
&=&\exp\left[4kf^2(n)+\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(\log n)^{3a}}{k}}\right)\right]\\
&\approx&e^{4(\log n)^a}
\end{array}$$
Using Chebyshev's inequality, it's straightforward to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, $\delta>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$,
$P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-1\right|>\epsilon\right)<\delta$, but I was hoping for a stronger result.  The discussion in answers and comments is discouraging, however.

Comment: This is very confusing for me : it seems that in your definition, $X_i$ depends also on $n$, so that it should be denoted by $X_{i,n}$, and you are interested in the pointwise behaviour of $\frac{1}{n} \sum_1^n X_{i,n}$. Right ? If it is the case, I'm not sure we can say anything a.s.

Comment: Only one of the random variables in the sequence depends on $n$ (the last one, $X_n$).  The average of the first $n-1$ random variables in the sequence (which is itself a random variable) also depends on $n$.  So, I am asking about pointwise behaviour of the sum of two random variables as $n\rightarrow\infty$, each of which depends on $n$.  Does that clarify?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{E}(X_1^2)$ depends on $n$, i can't see how $X_1$ doesn't depend on $n$.

Comment: You are correct, I am dealing with a triangular array here. I was going to ask you here why can't we say anything about a.s. convergence, but decided that it deserves its own question, which I posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624059/triangular-arrays-and-almost-sure-convergence-of-row-averages

Comment: This was just an intuition, maybe one can still say something, but I'm not optimistic. I'll look at your new question and its future answers.

Comment: @M.B.M. Why did you accept this answer?

Comment: @Did Because it seemed correct at the time. Now that I know more, I reversed my acceptance (sorry, Alex Becker).  This convergence and the triangular array business is pretty tricky, hence all my questions on it. However, I am learning...  thanks for your help everyone!  Btw, I edited the question, explaining where my random variables came from...

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As Ahriman points out, the $X_i$ are **not** identical for $i<n$ since $E[X_i^2]$ depends on $n$. The answer I give only applies for $X_i$ identical for $i<n$.

Yes. By the usual SLLN, you have
$$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}\mu$$
and since $\frac{n-1}{n}\to 1$ and $\frac{1}{n} X_n\to 0$ a.s., it follows that
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i= \frac{1}{n}X_n + \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} 0+1\cdot\mu=\mu.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I can see how $\frac{X_n}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$ (applying Borel-Cantelli lemma using Chebyshev's inequality since the variance is given).  This is what I was sort of thinking originally (the contribution of $X_n$ to the average being small, etc). However, my concern with this approach is that you can "prove" that the average $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}$ converges to zero almost surely that way, by noting that each random variable $\frac{X_i}{n-1}$ in the sum converges to zero almost surely, and then claiming that their sum is zero. (continued in next comment)

Comment: (continued from previous comment)  Obviously the example above is not true, but based on it not being true, I am worried about your proof (since it seems to use similar logic as my "proof").  Does your proof work because the number of items whose limits (each of which holds with probability one) you are adding in no way depends on the $n$ (i.e., my "proof" has two nested limits as $n\rightarrow\infty$, which, of course, is a no-no, while yours doesn't)  Could you please elaborate, maybe justify your next-to-last step (converge) a bit more?

Comment: Also, in the last line, is the second $X_i$ really $X_n$? (i.e. do you mean $\frac{1}{n}X_n$?)

Comment: @M.B.M. Thanks for the correction, that $X_i$ should indeed be $X_n$. When you ask "Does your proof work because the number of items whose limits (each of which holds with probability one) you are adding in no way depends on the n" that is precisely what happens. The justification for my next-to-last step is two standard facts about limits: 1. the product of a sequence converging to $a$ and a sequence converging to $b$ a.s. converges a.s. to $ab$ and 2. the sum of a limit converging a.s. to $a$ and a limit converging a.s. to $b$ converges to $a+b$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.  Additionally, I note that $a<1$ is very important here, because if $a\geq 1$, we wouldn't have the convergence $\frac{1}{n}X_n\rightarrow 0$ a.s. (or, at least, would not have been able to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma to show it).

Comment: @M.B.M. Indeed, you wouldn't have convergence at all.

Comment: Since the $X_i$'s depend also on $n$, this answer seems to be invalid. The original question remains open.

Comment: @Ahriman The dependence on $n$ is irrelevant, since $x_i$ for $i<n$ are independent of $n$.

Comment: @AlexBecker No, they are dependent of $n$, since $E(X_i^2)$ depends on $n$ when $i < n$.

Comment: @Ahriman Whoops! I didn't read that part, since I took the OP's statement that the $X_i$ are identical at face value.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Alex and @Ahriman.  I added the explanation of the origin of my random variable in my question. I don't think that it's possible to prove what I want...

Answer (score 1):

(If you'd like a counterexample, I'll expand this to a full answer. Otherwise, please give more information about your particular sequence $X$.)

This doesn't quite hold without extra assumptions on the sequence $X$. Fix b=1, a=1/2. Let

$$p_n = e^{-\sqrt{\log n}}$$ 
and 
$$ x_n = e^{2\sqrt{\log n}}.$$

Let $X_n$ be $x_n$ with probability $p_n$ and $0$ otherwise. $X_n$ has the appropriate mean and second moment. Now we'd like to show that the SLLN doesn't hold for this sequence.

Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$, sufficiently large. A little calculation shows that
$$ \mathbb{P}\left[\sum_{m=n(1-e^{-\sqrt{\log n}})}^nX_m \ge \frac n 2\right ] \ge \frac 1 2,$$

from which it follows that 
$$\limsup_n \frac {X_n} n \ge \frac 1 2,$$
a.s., by the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample.  I added an explanation to my question as to where my random variables came from...