# Triangular arrays and almost sure convergence of row averages

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose we have the triangular array $\{\{X_{in},i=1,\ldots,n\},n=1,2,\ldots\}$:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
X_{11}&&&&\\
X_{12}&X_{22}&&&\\
X_{13}&X_{23}&X_{33}&&\\
X_{14}&X_{24}&X_{34}&X_{44}&\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
\end{array}$$

Let the elements of each row be i.i.d., furthermore, let $E[X_{in}]=\mu<\infty$ in this array.

Now let $S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{in}$ be the average of each row.

I am confused as to why almost sure convergence results don't apply to $S_n$, i.e., why can't one claim that $S_n\xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}}\mu$?  Why doesn't the strong law of large numbers kick in here?

(I was going to put this in a comment where this came up in [one of my other questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623626/does-strong-law-of-large-numbers-hold-for-an-average-of-this-almost-i-i-d-seq), however, I thought that this warrants a separate question.)

Comment: Googling "strong law large numbers triangular arrays" gives links to some papers, showing that at least this question has been considered.

Comment: Indeed this is an arch-classical topic, dealt with in quite a few textbooks. Unfortunately, I am afraid I do not understand the question: why should almost sure convergence hold since the hypothesis of the setting where it holds (SLLN) is not met?

Answer (score 5):

Let $X_i$ be an i.i.d. sequence with $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_i=-1)=1/2$, and set $X_{in}=n X_i$. These random variables satisfy your conditions with $\mu=0$, but ${1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{in}=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ does not converge almost surely as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's a nice counterexample.  I am trying to think of cases when almost sure convergence might hold.  For instance, your counterexample would not work if we made *all* the elements of the triangular array i.i.d. (not just within each row).  Would the row average converge almost surely to $\mu$ in that case?